# How to upload multiple images using FaceBook Python SDK?

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I have three images image1.jpg ,image2.jpg, image3.jpg. I am trying to upload them as a single post. Below is my code:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
file1 = open("image1","rb")
file2 = open('image2', 'rb')
graph.put_photo(file1, 'Look at this cool photo!')
graph.put_photo(file2, 'Look at this cool photo!')
```

But they get uploaded as separate posts in separate images. How do I upload multiple images in single post?

Answer (score 5):

If someone looking to post Multiple Images or a Video in 2021 using Graph API in Python

```
import requests

auth_token = "XXXXXXXX"

def postImage(group_id, img):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/photos?access_token=" + auth_token
   
    files = {
            'file': open(img, 'rb'), 
            }
    data = {
        "published" : False
    }
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data).json()
    return r

def multiPostImage(group_id):
    imgs_id = []
    img_list = [img_path_1, img_path_2]
    for img in img_list:
        post_id = postImage(group_id ,img)
        
        imgs_id.append(post_id['id'])

    args=dict()
    args["message"]="Put your message here"
    for img_id in imgs_id:
        key="attached_media["+str(imgs_id.index(img_id))+"]"
        args[key]="{'media_fbid': '"+img_id+"'}"
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed?access_token=" + auth_token
    requests.post(url, data=args)

multiPostImage("426563960691001")
```

same way it work for page, use page_id instead of group_id

Posting a Video

```
def postVideo(group_id, video_path):
    url = f"https://graph-video.facebook.com/{group_id}/videos?access_token=" + auth_token
    files = {
            'file': open(video_path, 'rb'), 
            }
    requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to upload all photos and keep the id's (imgs_id).

Then, make a dict like args, and finally call request method.

```
    imgs_id = []
    for img in img_list:
        photo = open(img, "rb")
        imgs_id.append(api.put_photo(photo, album_id='me/photos',published=False)['id'])
        photo.close()

    args=dict()
    args["message"]="Put your message here"
    for img_id in imgs_id:
        key="attached_media["+str(imgs_id.index(img_id))+"]"
        args[key]="{'media_fbid': '"+img_id+"'}"

    api.request(path='/me/feed', args=None, post_args=args, method='POST')
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: [put-wall-post](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-wall-post) ? ..or `put-object`

`put-wall-post` might be what you are looking for:

> **attachment** - A dict that adds a structured attachment to the message being posted to the Wall. If you are sharing a URL, you will want to use the attachment parameter so that a thumbnail preview appears in the post. It should be a dict of the form:

Source: http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#api-reference